# Schema definition for MS Office and PDF documents

Tags: pdf, xls, docx, doc, xlsx

Our project involves parsing documents with structured content where user has to upload the schema of the documents that are coming in. Till now we have dealt only with XML so this was fine. But now requirement has come for xls(x), doc(x) and pdf.

Is there a schema definition for these document types? I can be sure that it may not be there for pdf but hoping there might be some way to have these for other types.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has the doucmentation of the Microsoft formats

- Binary (.doc, etc) formats:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313118(v=office.12).aspx
- XML (.docx, etc) formats:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548604(v=office.12).aspx

PDF is a page description language based on PostScript, so doesn't have a schema that makes semantic sense of the document contents.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Let me review these to see how it can help us